# Subversion repository layout, why?

Tags: svn, layout, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “branch”, “tag” and “trunk” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-really-mean)
>   [What is the reasoning behind the recommended layout for Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108682/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-recommended-layout-for-subversion-repositories)

I'm using Subversion for source control and I see that it follows some conventions about the directories structure. There are three directories at the project root : branch, tags, trunk.

What are the differences between these directories?

What are the recommendations about what to place in each directory?

Finally, what are the best practices about how to use this structure?

PS: My question is not related to the difference between the two different layouts (single repository or one repository per project).

Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a way to organize your code.

trunk: your usual development

tag: remember some specific version

branch: if you are working on several versions of the same code.

For best practices and a detail explanation check the official svn book. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/